# matlab differential equation

Tags: matlab, math, polynomial-math, differential-equations

I have the following differential equation which I'm not able to solve.

[image: differential equation]

We know the following about the equation:

D(r) is a third grade polynom

D'(1)=D'(2)=0

D(2)=2D(1)

u(1)=450

u'(2)=-K * (u(2)-Te)

Where K and Te are constants.

I want to approximate the problem using a matrix and I managed to solve
the similiar equation:[image: equationeasier] with the same limit conditions for u(1) and u'(2). 
On this equation I approximated u' and u'' with central differences and used a finite difference method between r=1 to r=2. I then placed the results in a matrix A in matlab and the limit conditions in the vector Y in matlab and ran u=A\Y to get how the u value changes. Heres my matlab code for the equation I managed to solve:

```
    clear
    a=1;
    b=2;
    N=100;
    h = (b-a)/N;
    K=3.20;
    Ti=450;
    Te=20;

    A = zeros(N+2);
    A(1,1)=1;
    A(end,end)=1/(2*h*K);
    A(end,end-1)=1;
    A(end,end-2)=-1/(2*h*K);


    r=a+h:h:b;

    %y(i)
    for i=1:1:length(r)
       yi(i)=-r(i)*(2/(h^2));
    end
    A(2:end-1,2:end-1)=A(2:end-1,2:end-1)+diag(yi);

    %y(i-1)
    for i=1:1:length(r)-1
        ymin(i)=r(i+1)*(1/(h^2))-1/(2*h);
    end
    A(3:end-1,2:end-2) = A(3:end-1,2:end-2)+diag(ymin);

    %y(i+1)
    for i=1:1:length(r)
       ymax(i)=r(i)*(1/(h^2))+1/(2*h);
    end
    A(2:end-1,3:end)=A(2:end-1,3:end)+diag(ymax);


    Y=zeros(N+2,1);
    Y(1) =Ti;
    Y(2)=-(Ti*(r(1)/(h^2)-(1/(2*h))));
    Y(end) = Te;
    r=[1,r];
    u=A\Y;
    plot(r,u(1:end-1));
```

My question is, how do I solve the first differential equation?

Comment: Though I can probably guess it from context, may I ask what your question is, and could you please add it to the question?

Comment: Gotcha.  The first differential equation is actually a cubic curve fit.  If I may just give you **a hint**: since you know the form of `D` (cubic) and have the four conditions, you can symbolically solve (using any tool you like) for the four cubic coefficients algebraically to obtain your required ratio without any further information.

Comment: @TroyHaskin I have attempted to do this, by substituting D(r) with Ar^3 + Br^2 + Cr + D, then going from there with the conditions. I am however unable to solve D(r). The only conditions I know how to use are D'(1)=D'(2)= 0 and D(2) = 2D(1). Only three conditions, so I can't solve it. Which is the fourth condition I should use?

Comment: That third condition is actually two conditions: `D(1) = alpha` and `D(2) = 2*alpha` where `alpha` is some arbitrary constant (you can call it anything; I chose `alpha`).

Comment: I still get an infinite amount of solutions. Does it not matter what alpha is?

Comment: It shouldn't.  I was able to solve for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` by leaving `alpha` as a variable in both Mathematica and Matlab (using the Symbolic Toolbox).  You shouldn't solve for `alpha`.

Comment: May I have a look at your code in matlab please? I've been trying to do this by hand, new to Matlab :)

Comment: I keep ending up at the same result now, both in Matlab and by hand. with a= -alpha
b=(9*alpha)/2
c=-6*alpha
d=3*alpha
Is this correct? I don't understand how alpha can be present in the answer.

Comment: What happens to `alpha` when you take the ratio?

Answer (score 0):

As TroyHaskin pointed out in comments, one can determine D up to a constant factor, and that constant factor cancels out in D'/D anyway. Put another way: we can assume that D(1)=1 (a convenient number), since D can be multiplied by any constant. Now it's easy to find the coefficients ([done with Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+a%2Bb%2Bc%2Bd+%3D+1%2C+8a%2B4b%2B2c%2Bd%3D2%2C+3a%2B2b%2Bc%3D0%2C+12a%2B4b%2Bc%3D0)), and the polynomial turns out to be

D(r) = -2r^3+9r^2-12r+6

with derivative D'(r) = -6r^2+18r-12.  (There is also a smarter way to find the polynomial by starting with D', which is quadratic with known roots.)

I would probably use this information right away, computing the coefficient k of the first derivative:

```
r = a+h:h:b;
k = 1+r.*(-6*r.^2+18*r-12)./(-2*r.^3+9*r.^2-12*r+6);
```

It seems that k is always positive on the interval [1,2], so if you want to minimize the changes to existing code, just replace r(i) by r(i)/k(i) in it.

---

By the way, instead of loops like

```
for i=1:1:length(r)
   yi(i)=-r(i)*(2/(h^2));
end
```

one usually does simply

```
yi=-r*(2/(h^2));
```

This *vectorization* makes the code more compact and can benefit the performance too (not so much in your example, where solving the linear system is the bottleneck). Another benefit is that yi is properly initialized, while with your loop construction, if yi happened to already exist and have length greater than length(r), the resulting array would have extraneous entries. (This is a potential source of hard-to-track bugs.)